# Exceptions in functions

Tags: functions, soft-question

I have recently started studying functions(topics such as periodicity, odd/even, into/onto, etc.). I was wondering if there are any strange exceptions to the general rule that is taught?

Comment: Which "general rule" are you referring to?

Comment: Well General rules such as methods for finding period, or ways to determine whether function is odd/even. For example, the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ seems to be even at first glance (as substituting $-x$ gives the same equation). However, upon graphing it, we see differently.

Comment: Regarding "rules" in math, if there were exceptions to them then we wouldn't call them rules.  So I'd say no, there are no strange exceptions, rules are rules.

Comment: Equations aren't called "even"; instead, one would say the graph is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. The graph of $x^2+y^2=1$ indeed has this property (it's the unit circle).

Comment: Well call them generalizations then @gregorygrant

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Dirichlet function](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/nowhere-continuous-function/) which is periodic but doesn't have a smallest period.

Or the always vanishing function which is odd and even.